# How to customize Logitech trackball (M575) button options?

Tags: logitech

I tried using Solaar, but apparently M575 isn't supported.

Does anyone have other options? I'd like to change the pointer speed as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Changing speed doesn't require any special software, unlike mapping additional buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Settings] > [Mouse & Touchpad] > Mouse block has a bar and indicator, drag the indicator to the left to slow the pointer, to the right to speed up the pointer.  It works with my Logitech M575.

Answer (score 0):

EasyStroke comes with Ubuntu. Confirmed with M570 and M575. EasyStroke is an application which can recognize gestures made by pointing devices such as mouse, pen, finger, etc.